# Using ReactJS with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am trying to use ReactJS with AngularJS but it is not working out. Could anyone please direct me on how to gel them together? Or please point out what am missing here?

My index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <title>My Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <div id="myDiv">
            <button id="btn1" data-ng-click="clickMe()">Click Me</button>
        </div>
        <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.8.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.8.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/jsx" src="reactExample.js"></script>
        <script src="angularExample.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is how my reactExample.js has been written:

```
/**
  * @jsx React.DOM
  */
var testMy = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return ( <p>Hello</p>)
    }
});
```

And my angularExample.js is as follows:

```
var myapp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
myapp.controller('Ctrl1',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.clickMe = function(){
        alert("Clicked!");
        React.renderComponent(testMy, elem[0]);
    }
}]);
```

It does not display anything (other than the alert). Am expecting to see 'Hello' printed there but it throws the following error in the console:

```
Error: Invariant Violation: prepareEnvironmentForDOM(...): Target container is not a DOM element
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe fix your code samples? The formatting is hard to read

Answer (score 20):

Already @Simon Smith mentioned why the error occour `React.renderComponent` expect second argument but the way you play DOM manipulation inside controller is not appropriate. In `AngularJs` DOM manipulation should be in `directive`. Lets see how it could be

From [**Facebook's React vs AngularJS: A Closer Look**](http://www.quora.com/Pete-Hunt/Posts/Facebooks-React-vs-AngularJS-A-Closer-Look) blog

> React components are far more powerful than Angular templates; they should be compared with Angular's directives instead.

Bottom of this blog **Using React and AngularJS together** section you can see how `angular` and `react` can play together.

From [**react**](http://facebook.github.io/react/) website

> React components implement a render() method that takes input data and returns what to display.

In `angularjs` components are rendered by `directive`

See this [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oJF4VXQzS8xFa6SVxqrh?p=preview) where I integrate `angularjs` and `react`.

In `react-example.js` I have created `virtual dom` element

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({}, 'Hello ' + this.props.name);
  }
});
```

And `myMessage` directive render the `virtual dom`

```
React.renderComponent(Hello({name: scope.myModel.message}), document.getElementById('example'));
```

Where `virtual dom`'s `name` property will bind with `scope.myModel.message`

Comment: I have forked the plunker and modified it so that the `Hello` component is contained within the directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/3ImY8G7X1VfvOeKrC8DY?p=preview

@Reza does this make much sense?

Comment: Technically this is not a problem but `Separation of Concern (SoC)` and test-ability perspective it is better to place your react classes into different files.

Answer (score 12):

To use React in my controller, i do this

```
 myApp.controller(function($scope){
        $scope.myComponent = {};
        $scope.myComponent.setState({data: "something"});
    });
```

and in my React component:

```
window.myComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
           data:''
        }
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
       var scope = this.props.scope;
           scope.myComponent = this;
    },
    render:func .....
});
```

I'm using the [ngReact](https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact) directive from David Chang, which passes the $scope as a property into a component.  So now you can call setState from your controller, forcing the react component to re-render :)

I have a bigger example of above in my [React-Sandbox](https://github.com/mwq27/React-Sandbox)

Comment: How would data binding work the other way? Say your react component has an input and you want to update the angular scope when the input changes. Is this possible with the react-component directive from ngReact.

Answer (score 9):

I would consider doing the integration via a directive as that is often the recommended approach for integrating non angular code with angular.

Here is an example:

```
angular.module('app').directive('greeting',[function(){
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        scope:{name:'@'},
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
            var GreetingSection = React.createClass({displayName: 'Greeting',
                render: function() {
                    var message = "Good morning " + this.props.data.name + ", how are you?";
                    return React.createElement('div', {className: "greeting"},message);
                }
            });
            React.renderComponent(GreetingSection({data:scope}), elem[0]);
        }
    };
}]);
```

More info here (link died; points to archive.org copy):
[http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/547bbd04fa0710440b45e41c](https://web.archive.org/web/20180805021910/http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/547bbd04fa0710440b45e41c)

Comment: Can you explain why I was getting this error when using this code? `Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined at ReactClass.createClass.Constructor`  I had to instead use `React.createFactory` to create a greetingFactory variable and pass the `greetingFactory` variable into `React.render` instead of `React.renderComponent`.

Comment: @taco In the latest version of react (v0.14.x), you need to do ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(GreetingSection, null), elem[0]);
to avoid this error. See [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)

Comment: @DamianGreen maybe that will help somebody else. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!! You saved my day!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead try using ngReact angular module rather than using ReactJs directly. This provides seamless integration with angularJs as well. Check the samples/examples @ https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact

Answer (score 2):

`renderComponent` expects a DOM element as a second argument to inject the component. It seems that is what the error is complaining about.